# SQL Server : conditional case in where clause

Tags: sql-server, case, where-clause

I would like to write the following as a `CASE` statement in my `WHERE` clause, but I'm unsure how to write it.

```
if @Result = '' then 
    [Result] = @Result
else
    [Result] like @Result + '%'
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work.

```
Declare @Result varchar(100)

Set @Result  =''

Select * 
From    dbo.TABLE
Where [Result] Like Case 
            When @Result = '' Then @Result
            Else @result + '%'
            End
```

Comment: bang on mate. Many thanks, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is what exactly same as your `if else` statement

```
WHERE [Result] LIKE (CASE @Result WHEN '' THEN @Result ELSE @Result + '%' END)
```